# Explain the output of the following c program

Tags: c

For the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;

int main( )
{
    int i, j, temp;
    i=5;
    j=10;
    temp=0;
    if( i > j)
        swap ( i, j );
    printf ( "%d %d %d", i, j, temp);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output which i tested with different compilers :

```
10 0 0
```

I understand that had j been 5 and i been 10 the output would have been swapped. But, in this particular program the if statement is not executed. So, can someone please explain the reason why i get this output?

Comment: It would be better if you just write the three lines of code in-place. There's no need for a macro here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the macro `swap` with brackets.

```
if (i > j)
{
    swap(i, j);
}
```

Don't forget that a macro is simply a copy-paste operation performed by the pre-processor which results in the following:

```
temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
```

If you don't wrap it you end up with:

```
if (i > j)
    temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
```

I don't think this is what you intended... :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your `swap` macro results in three statements, and only the first one becomes part of the `if` statement.

The idiomatic way of writing such a macro is:

```
#define swap(a, b) \
    do { temp = a; a = b; b = temp; } while (0)
```

Although using only brackets, omitting the `do` and `while (0)`, may appear to work, it will fail in situations like this:

```
if (something)
    swap(a, b);
else
    something
```

In this code, the author treats `swap` as a normal function call, not knowing that the semicolon should be omitted. After preprocessing, this expands to:

```
if (something)
    { temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }
;
else
    something
```

This results in a compilation error, since the `else` does not immediately follow a single statement after the `if`. Using the `do … while (0)` form results in code such that `swap(a, b);` is exactly a single statement and may be used anywhere a normal function call in that form may be used.

Comment: +1 for including the `do {} while(0)` approach and the problems that can arise using it (under certain conditions). You wouldn't have to worry about it if you always wrap your statements in `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

After expansion of the macro you code will look like

```
if( i > j)
     temp=i; 
i=j; 
j=temp;
```

This is not what you expect like:

```
if( i > j)
{
     temp=a; 
     a=b; 
     b=temp;
}
```

Comment: Actually it would expand to `temp=i; i=j; j=temp;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp; Yes. That was typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
As an alternative to wrapping the macro in brackets...
#define swap(a,b) {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}

You could also replace the semicolons to ensure the macro expands to a single statement...
#define swap(a,b) temp=a, a=b, b=temp;
```

I prefer the 'bracket' approach as it better illustrates scope.